# WPF Bind different sources to combobox

Tags: wpf, binding, combobox

I have a user control composed from a text box and a combo box. 
What i am trying to achieve is to bind the combo box item source to different sources based on the data from text box.

For example: i have the text box input : 2meters and i want the combo box to be populated with the length units and so on. so the source for the combo box will be based on the text box as length units, mass etc.

Can anyone help me figure this out?

Regards.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well I would use another approach. How about something that sticks to MVVM?

```
// class for all units you want to show in the UI
public class MeasureUnit : ViewModelBase // base class implementing INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    private bool _isSelectable;
    // if an item should not be shown in ComboBox IsSelectable == false
    public bool IsSelectable
    {
        get { return _isSelectable; }
        set
        {
            _isSelectable = value;
            RaisePropertyChanged(() => IsSelectable);
        }
    }

    private string _displayName;
    // the entry shown in the ComboBox
    public string DisplayName
    {
        get { return _displayName; }
        set
        {
            _displayName= value;
            RaisePropertyChanged(() => DisplayName);
        }
    }
}
```

Now I assume that you have a VM with the following property, which will be used as `DataContext` for the `ComboBox`.

```
private ObservableCollection<MeasureUnit> _units;
public ObservableCollection<MeasureUnit> Units
{
    get { return _units ?? (_units = new ObservableCollection<MeasureUnit>()); }
}
```

The usage in the frontend could look like this.

```
<ComboBox ItemsSource="{Binding Units}" DisplayMemberPath="DisplayName" ...>
    <ComboBox.Resources>
        <BooleanToVisibiltyConverter x:Key="Bool2VisConv" />
    </ComboBox.Resources>
    <ComboBox.ItemTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
            <ContentPresenter Content="{Binding}" 
                 Visibility="{Binding IsSelectable, Converter={StaticResource Bool2VisConv}}"/>
        </DataTemplate>
    </ComboBox.ItemTemplate>
</ComboBox>
```

Now you only need to implement some logic, which sets the `IsSelectable` property of the items in the `Units` collection. The `ComboBox` will only show the items, where `IsSelectable` is set to `true`.